# getall function in PHP

Tags: php, oop

What is wrong in my class.It;s giving me  syntax error, unexpected ','  on my getall function.Is is not possible to send multiple return value? What would be the problem.

```
class Form
{
private $name;
private $email;
private $pass;
private $rpass;
private $phone;

public static function setname($name)//setting name
{
    $this->name=$name;
}
public static function email($email)//setting email
{
    $this->email=$email;
}
public static function password($pass)//setting password
{
    $this->pass=$pass;
}
public static function repassword($rpass)//password again
{
    $this->rpass=$rpass;
}
public static function phone($phone)
{
    $this->phone=$phone;
}

 public static function getall() //getting all value
{
  $a=$this->name;
  $b=$this->email;
  $c=$this->pass;
  $d=$this->rpass;
  $e=$this->phone;
  return($a,$b,$c,$d,$e);//here is the problem
}
```

}

Comment: If you're trying to return array of values you should use `array($a,$b,$c,$d,$e);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to return an array, but what you have is invalid syntax it doesn't mean anything.

So change this:

```
return($a,$b,$c,$d,$e);
```

to this:

```
return [$a,$b,$c,$d,$e];
     //^   See here   ^
```

For more information about arrays see the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax

Also you can't have static functions with `$this`. Because `$this` is only accessible in object syntax, but not in the class itself, so I think you want to remove the static keyword from the functions.

Comment: Thanks.It's good now .But it's giving now  an undefined index context in  $this->name=$name. @Rizier123

Comment: sorry There are some other problem

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: name in G:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\app\controllers\Register.php on line 61

Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in G:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\core\Form.php on line 13

Comment: @ it's ok now.But In my Register.php I'm using static way to call it and it is not giving me error.  Form::setname($_POST['name']); But my setname() is not static method any more.It's getting the value.